# if (x < … || and >= …) — Why does this not compile?

Tags: java

When I compile this code:

```
if (yPix < 0 || >= render.LENGTH) …
```

I get the following two errors:

> *Syntax error on token `>=`, delete this token.*

and

> *The operator `||` is undefined for the argument type(s) `boolean`, `int`.*

How do I fix this? I am new to Java.

Comment: Hi, Stanley. This question does not really conform to the rules for the P.SE site. It *might* be on topic on StackOverflow.com, our sister site, but it might be considered too trivial, either (IMO). Since you already have an answer, it probably won't get migrated, but in future cases, you should consult the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a left-hand argument for the boolean operator. It should be:

```
if (yPix < 0 || yPix >= render.LENGTH) …
//              ^^^^
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! I have to wait 8 mins for to mark your answer as correct.